# Add UITableViewCell to a UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an application which can rearrange the order of the `UITableViewCells` and can delete the cells. However, I need help in adding new cells to the `UITableView` when a button is pressed and a way to save the order of the rearranged cells.

Here is the code in the `ViewController.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if (!maTheData) {
    maTheData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bus", @"Truck", @"Car",nil];


}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [maTheData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath           *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tvcItems"];
UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
[lblName setText:[maTheData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [maTheData removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    // Delete row using the cool literal version of [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Insert something into the array, and you can just add a populated NSIndexPath of   data or simplr reload data
    [maTheData addObject:@"I'm a new item!"];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
NSString *mover = [maTheData objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
[maTheData removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
[maTheData insertObject:mover atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your IBAction method (the method connected to your button) you just add a new entry to your maTheData and call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

```c
- (IBAction)addAction:(id)sender {   
  [self.maTheData addObject:@"A string object"];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I dont have a button. maTheData is a NSMutableArray

Comment: You said ... when a button is pressed ?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't programmed the button

Comment: Arman. Reloading the data calls your tableView's dataSource methods again and does everything you want. There is nothing left to do. You can find sample implementations under the `UITableView`'s class documentation